# C++ Error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, syntax-error, instance

I have a class called `MainWindow` without a default constructor. I have a class called `Application`, its constructor uses an instance of `MainWindow` as a parameter. I get an

```
 Error C2512, "no appropriate default constructor available"
```

in the definition of the constructor from the class Application.

Here's the code of the constructor:

```
Application::Application(HINSTANCE hInstance, MainWindow mainWindow) {...}
```

I'm creating the instance of `Application` like this:

```
MainWindow window(1000, 1000, false, "test");
Application program(Instance, window);
```

Why do I get this error? I'm not trying to create a new instance of MainWindow with the default constructor.

Comment: Does `Application` have a `MainWindow` data member? If so, then you would be default constructing it.

Comment: How do you create the Application object?  Post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that class Application has a data member of type MainWindow, that can not be created. Otherwise it is not clear why the constructor of class Application has parameter `MainWindow mainWindow`. I think it is used that to assign it to the data member of the class.

You could use the ctor-initializer. For example if class Application indeed has a data member of type MainWindow (let name it m_window) then you could write the constructor the following way

```
Application::Application(HINSTANCE hInstance, MainWindow mainWindow) : m_window( mainWindow )
{
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is no a MainWindow class member then your Application class has a constructor which takes a MainWindow parameter by value. In order to do this it must create a copy of window, if you have no copy constructor, the compiler may be looking for some way to create this copy. Try:

Application::Application(HINSTANCE hInstance, MainWindow &mainWindow) {...}